# N.I. Massive assign Pitch Bend Wheel to Macro

Tags: midi, synthesizer

How do I assign the pitch bend wheel in Massive to any parameter control, like a macro? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 3):

Can you assign a parameter in NI's Massive to the MIDI Pitch bend wheel?

No, I don't think you can, Pitch Bend and Aftertouch have dedicated controllers(They aren't in the standard MIDI CC# 1-127 which Massive sees) - Meaning they won't show up in the list of CC#s in Massive.

You may be able to do it with MIDI monitoring/editing software.

Comment: Could tell me more about MIDI monitoring/editing software? Is this a dedicated software that operates parallel to my DAW? Do you have examples of this kind of software?

Comment: Yes, It does. You route the keyboard to the MIDI software, and then from the MIDI software to the music software. I have never used any of these myself, and I won't be in the studio for a few days to try any of them out with PB. The ones I can find are; Bome's MIDI Translator, MIDI-OX and MidiPipe for Mac.

Answer (score 2):

Massive doesn't let you macro the pitch of the synth.

In order to do this you can either macro the individual OSC pitch values, or set the pitch range in the "Pitchbend" section of the "OSC" tab and modulate the pitchbend in your midi control.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? It's a bit abstract now.

Comment: What daw do you use?

Comment: Pro Tools 11 on Windows 8.1

Comment: You should read Chapter 29 Midi Editing in the Pro Tools Resource Guide

Answer (score 2):

I use Ableton - Live and I can automatize the pitchbend parameter of Massive.

Go to Massive's osc tab (where is the glide and the vibrato), there is a pitchbend section where you can adjust the Up and Down range expressed in semitones. I usually use Up 12 and Down 12.
Then in Live you create a midi clip, at the left of the keyboard there is a CLIP section, below it there is a "E" button for opening the enveloppes. There you can automatize things like volume, balance and pitchbend.

Comment: this appears to be what works best for making the pitch bend work.