# Automate MIDI pitch in Ableton w/ 3rd Party Plugin Instrument

Tags: ableton, live, automation, plugin

Checked out this but it didn't help me all the way [N.I. Massive assign Pitch Bend Wheel to Macro](https://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/35436/n-i-massive-assign-pitch-bend-wheel-to-macro)

I have an ableton rack with an instance of massive.  I have my MIDI clip opened, clicked the `(E)` envelope button to bring up the envelope view, selected `MIDI Ctrl` and `Pitch Bend`. When I make a change to the envelope, the pitch doesn't change...It goes up to 8191 (I'm assuming cents).

How can I automate pitch bends of MIDI this way?

Comment: not sure what you are asking here - can you edit your post to clarify a) what you are trying to do, and b) what isn't working.

Comment: Downvote? A) "Automate MIDI pitch in Ableton w/ 3rd Party Plugin Instrument" and B) "When I make a change to the envelope".  I specifically mentioned both of your concerns.  I don't think a downvote was necessary on this.  I'm trying to automate the pitch of my MIDI instrument in the MIDI clip using the envelopes.  When I automate it, the pitch doesn't change.  How does that not make sense enough for you to downvote me?

Comment: O.rka - I have not downvoted you

Comment: Sorry about that @RoryAlsop. I thought the question was clear but I can elaborate more.

Answer (score 0):

Your method is correct. First try a single instance of just Massive in your MIDI track, not a rack with macros. Also, make sure Massive reacts to pitch bend. Got to the OSC tab and make sure Pitchbend is something else than 0 for up and down. Good luck!

Hens Zimmerman

[image: blah blah biddie blah]

Comment: I made it +24 and -24 but it's still not working